# Render openlayers on jsp page

Tags: jsp, openlayers

How to render openlayers on a jsp page? I am using a tomcat server and I have some data in my database. I want the map to be displayed on a jsp page.

Comment: *"How to render openlayers on a jsp page?"* The same way you'd render it on an HTML page.

Comment: check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576997/how-to-use-openlayers-map?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented Open Layers map on a jsp page.
you need 3 things.

1st- basic UI structure - appropriate div containers for display of your information which should contain div container for map.

2nd- business logic - to show relevant information(vector) on the map. data fetch code and business logic(written in java on a jsp page) must contain calls to javascript functions(of OpenLayers/Leaflet/Google API) and the information that needs to be shown on map using function(javascript) arguments and scriptlet tags .

3rd- javascript file/code to render map(with infomation) in the div container.